# Show that a triangle is equilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

> A circle crosses the sides of a triangle, dividing each of them into
>   three equal parts. Prove that the triangle is equilateral.

[image]

I think that the best way is to show that $\angle BAC = \angle ABC$, and then $\angle ABC = \angle ACB$. Something like that and I would be very grateful if you could help me because I don't see how this can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the power of a point theorem, $$AD\cdot AE=AK\cdot AF$$

$$2 AD^2 = 2 AK^2 $$

That means that $ AC = 3 AD = 3 AK = AB$

Analogically $BA=BC$

Comment: We haven't studied this Theorem yet. Is it this one: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/PPower.shtml?

Comment: I think it is much simpler to write the second equation as $$\frac29 AB^2=\frac29AC^2.$$

Comment: @NikolDimitrova yes. It is proven by similarity of triangles.